# Laravel Searchbar Function Returns Undefined Key

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

My laravel searchbar is returning Undefined Key. It is returning Undefined Key: 'Search' Here is the controller function:

```
    public function search() {
        $search = $_GET['search'];
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('intro', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_1_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_1_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_2_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_2_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_3_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_3_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_4_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_4_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_5_heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('row_5_body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('conclusion', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->get();

        return view('pages/search', compact('posts'));
    }
```

Here is the searchbar form:

```
        <form class="d-flex" role="search" id="searchbar" type="get" action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
          <input class="form-control me-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" id="searchbtn">Search</button>
        </form>
```

And here is the route:

```
Route::get('/search', [PagesController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error "Undefined Key: 'Search'" usually occurs when accessing an array key that doesn't exist. $_GET['search'] seems not set.  To fix this, you can check if $_GET['search'] is set before using it.

Comment: @karl hill i think its because it isn't seeing what the user is inputting from the searchbar but i dont know how to fix this

Comment: How are you sending the search request. Check to make sure that $_GET['search'] is set by using dd($_GET['search']);  Before searching your table you should confirm this by using $search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : ''; or similar

Answer (score 0):

your given code is working fine.

just confirm that your query string is correct like so.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew4tL.png)